# Any way to generate Animation-List automatically?

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation

I have some 240 images that I want to play as an animation as a background. I know that seems a bit much, but I was wondering if the Animation-List can somehow be automatically generated or if some workaround exists. Because copying in the names of 240 images is not easy. And if there is some other way to do this, I'd be delighted to know it, too.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html and use addFrame()

Comment: Hmm, it could be my misunderstanding, but won't I still have to add every frame manually?